# Article before numbered nouns

Tags: articles

Are these sentences correct without articles, please? Is this the same case as *in equation (3)*?

> I check (the) key 2016.

> In was in (the) test 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we don't use an article in this context.

> The patient is in Ward 5.
>
> I live at Number 18.

Comment: We also capitalise the noun.*